# Why online judge is giving me an Runtime error?

Tags: c++

In the UVA problem "100 The 3n + 1 problem" when i submit the code it says runtime error. The code is in C++

https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36

I tried many things but i still cannot solve that problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#define ll long long
#define N 10000

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int cont = 0, aux = 0;
    ll n1, n2, m; 

    ll dp[N] = {0};

    while (cin >> n1 >> n2) {
        cout << n1 << " " << n2 << " ";
        if(n1 > n2)
        {
            m = n2;
            n2 = n1;
            n1 = m;
        }
        for (ll i = n1; i <= n2; i++) {
            ll num = i;
            if (num == 1) {
                cont = 1;
            }
            else{
                if (dp[num] != 0){
                    cont = dp[num];
                }
                else {
                    while (num >= 1){
                        if (num == 1) {
                            cont += 1;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (num%2 != 0){
                            num = (3 * num) + 1;
                        }
                        else{
                            num = num/2;
                        }
                        cont += 1;
                    }
                    dp[num] = cont;
                }
            }
            aux = max(aux, cont);
            cont = 0;
        }
        cout << aux << "\n";
        aux = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you run your program through valgrind?  Compile with any sanitizers turned on?  Anything to help figure out where the runtime error is coming from?

Comment: `Runtime error` is not enough info for us to help you. Please elaborate more.

Comment: [Consider using fuzzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing) to find a failure case, then run the program through a debugger with the failure case.

Comment: The problem maybe at `dp[N]` as it only creates array from `0->9999`

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Note, though, that even if they say "All integers
will be less than 10,000 and greater than 0.", they may be lying. Please also note that you are **not** exploiting any memoization at all, since the line `dp[num] = cont;` is *after* the loop `while (num >= 1){ if (num == 1) {... break;} ... }`. Inside that loop, `num` can become (a lot) greater than 10000, but outside...

Answer (score 0):

The limit on input is 1,000,000 (not 10,000). The limit is stated wrong.

Similar problem:
https://www.spoj.com/problems/PROBTNPO/